# ITKMathematicalMorphology library not generated (MSVC 11)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, itk

I followed instructions in http://www.itk.org/Wiki/ITK/Configuring_and_Building/VisualStudio but I'm using Studio 12 (which is VC11?).

I used cmake GUI, which seemed to generate all the visual studio projects.
I loaded ITK.SLN, from the top level of cmake-guis target, into VS and it ran saying it had no errors.

However, when I go to where it generate the libs there is no ITKMathematicalMorphology.lib.

One of the projects listed in Visual Studio is ITKMathematicalMorphology-all.  It apparently has no source code (the ITKMathematicalMorphology-all project has no Source Files section).  According to ITKs That library has a function called GrayscaleFillholeImageFilter but there is no file in the entire build directory tree (cmake-gui's target) with that string.

Comment: Could you clearify your question?

Answer (score 1):

That is expected. ITK is a template library so not every module has a compile library. This module is only templated classes.

There is no error here.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that might be the case but then I figured if that was the case then I should at least be able to find a source file with one of its function/class./method names but I searched the entire build directory for "[GrayscaleFillholeImageFilter](http://www.itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1GrayscaleFillholeImageFilter.html)" and came up empty.

Comment: Because it is in the source directory